# rails console - display active record results in a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, console, irb

Is there a way to display Active Record results in table format in the script/console environment?

Answer (score 37):

Yep. There's a gem called [hirb](http://github.com/cldwalker/hirb) that does this very well.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Sorry but I can't vote your answer because I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 11):

Also check out http://tableprintgem.com. It's an efficient way to view a list of structured data, making it easy to scan and compare across large swaths of records (and for many people, it's a comfortable return to the SQL command line output of yesteryear :)

[image: table_print ruby gem - explore your data]

The most powerful feature of table_print is the ability to see your data in the context of other objects it relates to. You can reference nested objects with the method chain required to reach them. This example is showing data from three different tables:

- **name** from the Author table (reached through author.name)
- **title** from the Book table (reached through author.books.title)
- **caption** from the Photo table (reached through author.books.photos.caption)

[image: table_print ruby gem - contextualize your data]

There's a short intro screencast at http://tableprintgem.com

(full disclosure: I wrote this gem)

Comment: Couldn't you do the last thing with normal SQL queries, or the the rails method chain, to get such printouts with other table gems like hirb?

Comment: I'm a big fan, but you should disclose that this is your gem.

Comment: oh yeah, thanks. *I* know it's mine, sometimes I forget other people aren't in my head :)